# How To Set Alarm While Using Tab View

Tags: android, android-alarms

I have little knowledge about setting alarms in android; I have written some code for setting an alarm, as shown bellow; it worked fine for me when using a single activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ReminderService.class);
intent.putExtra("ti", name);  
intent.putExtra("id", id); 
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getBaseContext(), id,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager =(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);   
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

This code does not work in tab view. please help me.

Comment: Please Guide How To handle alarm in tabview ..